# How can I build a table into an alcove?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, desk

I have this weird portion of a second bedroom where about 4 foot of it is 2 feet deeper than the rest of the wall.

[image]

What I want to do is fix a butcher block in that space to use as a desk.
What is the best way to mount this? I would be mounting it to drywall fronted studs / fire barrier. Will anchoring it in the studs and fire barrier at multiple points.

Is this a good plan or should I be looking into other procedures? I'd rather not buy desk legs if I can mount it to the wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just buy a 1x4 or similar material that would go with your butcher block and use them as a ledger board on the three sides.  Simply measure the height you want, attach ledger board to wall all the way around (3 easy cuts) and attach them to the studs.

Then just slide on your butcher block.  To attach to ledger you can use screws but a little silicone is probably more than enough for a tight space to keep it from moving.

Answer (score 2):

As DMoore notes, a simple ledger would work well. If you want something that isn't visible, buy yourself a Kreg pocket screw jig like [this one](https://www.kregtool.com/store/c13/kreg-jigsreg/p114/kreg-jigreg-mini/). Cut a few 2x4 to hold it up at the right spot, and then you can just screw it right in. I would try to use 2 screws per 2x4 to increase the strength.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the fire barrier is specifically but in general you should be able to mount a floating top in this situation without any problems. You can do angle brackets, z clips, or ledgers(by far the easiest). The hardest part is going to be scribe-ing in all three sides to your walls. One trick is to do the ledger, paint it to match your walls, then set the top with just the front inch of the sides that meet the capturing walls tight, then apply a back splash out of the same material as the top to cover the gap. Cheers!